# write from app web to google spreedsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I try of a dev solution for my company and I'm stuck with API of google sheets. I trying of write a page of googlesheets and my code no run without show me any error. I will greatfull for your asist.

```
/* exported gapiLoaded */
/* exported gisLoaded */
/* exported handleAuthClick */
/* exported handleSignoutClick */

// TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
const CLIENT_ID = '417439781945-jtcarehtqmqscff6bdhd18dcp9tgi83m.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDubc8Tb2qI9NUNPg8ZNFQ91NkfUqzhSO4';

// Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';

let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;

document.getElementById('gapi').addEventListener("load", gapiLoaded);
document.getElementById('gis').addEventListener("load", gisLoaded);

document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

/**
 * Callback after api.js is loaded.
 */
function gapiLoaded() {
  gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
}

/**
 * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
 * discovery doc to initialize the API.
 */
async function initializeGapiClient() {
  await gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
  });
  gapiInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
 * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
 */
function gisLoaded() {
  tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: '', // defined later
  });
  gisInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

/**
 * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
 */
function maybeEnableButtons() {
  if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

/**
 *  Sign in the user upon button click.
 */
function handleAuthClick() {
  tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
    if (resp.error !== undefined) {
      throw (resp);
    }
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
    await listMajors();
  };

  if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
  } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
  }
}

/**
 *  Sign out the user upon button click.
 */
function handleSignoutClick() {
  const token = gapi.client.getToken();
  if (token !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
    gapi.client.setToken('');
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

/**
 * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
 * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
 */
async function listMajors() {
  let response;
  try {
    // Fetch first 10 files
    response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: '1qO9JaCVAw4ezMljdN0tjI1hxx5tnctMd7e8_B3i4Tpc',
      range: 'Trabajos!A2:D',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  const range = response.result;
  if (!range || !range.values || range.values.length == 0) {
    console.warn('No se encontraron valores');
    return;
  }

  const macAddress = getMacAddress();
  const newDate = newDateNow();

  range.values.forEach( async(trabajo) => {
    const [numerotrabajo, responsable, fecha] = trabajo;
    await enviarTrabajoConDatosExtras(numerotrabajo, responsable, macAddress, newDate)
  });
}

    function getMacAddress() {
        if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") > 0) {
            return window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency;
        } else {
            return "No disponible";
        }
    }

    function newDateNow() {
        const now = new Date();
        const fecha = now.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        const hora = now.toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
        return `${fecha} ${hora}`;
    }

    
    async function enviarTrabajoConDatosExtras(numerotrabajo, responsable, macAddress, newDate) {
        console.log('Enviando trabajo:', numerotrabajo, responsable, macAddress, newDate);


        const spreadsheetId = '1qO9JaCVAw4ezMljdN0tjI1hxx5tnctMd7e8_B3i4Tpc';
        const range = 'Trabajos!A:D';
    
        const values = [
            [numerotrabajo, macAddress, newDate]
        ];
    
        try {
            const response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
                spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
                range: range,
                valueInputOption: 'RAW',
                insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
                resource: {
                    values: values
                }
            });
    
            console.log('Trabajo enviado con éxito:', response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error al enviar el trabajo:', error);
        }

    }
```

and the button the inicialize session in google disappeared too.

I try of inicialize session en google and write a document in googlesheets, me and other three persons inicialize sesion without problem.

Comment: Please rotate the API key you've now published to the world. Just editing it out of your post is not enough.